# disabled listitems in alertdialog does not show up as grayed out items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

This is my scenario.

I have an activity in which i have to show a dialog box (which is a listview wit two options OptionA and OptionB).
The listview that i used is in single choice mode. But sometimes Option A is disabled(the user is not allowed to select Option A)

These are my code fragments

```
private void createDialog() {
    boolean disableOptionA = false;
    ...
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.codec_title));

    ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> modeAdapter = CustomMenuAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.codec_decoder,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, disableOptionA);
    modeList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
    builder.setView(modeList);
    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
...
}
```

The codec_decoder array contains the two options OptionA and OptionB. The code for the CustomMenuAdapter is as follows.

```
public class CustomMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> {

    boolean disableOptionA = true;

    private CustomMenuAdapter(Context context, int textViewResId, CharSequence[] strings, boolean disableOptionA) {
        super(context, textViewResId, strings);
        this.disableOptionA = disableOptionA;
    }

    public static CustomMenuAdapter createFromResource(Context context, int textArrayResId, int textViewResId,
            boolean disableOptionA) {

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        CharSequence[] strings = resources.getTextArray(textArrayResId);

        return new CustomMenuAdapter(context, textViewResId, strings, disableOptionA);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.setEnabled(isEnabled(position));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            if (disableOptionA) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

now everything works well, but when the OptionA is disabled, it acts disabled but looks like its enabled, it does **NOT** get grayed out.
Any ideas?

Comment: have you solved this problem yet?

Comment: Works great in my case. Thanks

Comment: From latest API versions I noticed, around disabled items, that the divider line between entries is missing. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is replace the following code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        if (disableOptionA) {
            return false;
        }
     }
    return true;
   }
```

with
In case i want to disable my item on position 1:

```
     @Override
     public boolean isEnabled(int position) {

    if (position == 1)
        return true;

    return false;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

@Override
     public boolean isEnabled(int position) {

```
if (position == 1)
    return true;
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to your answer. Don't post code only answers.